# how to get data from url in Angular 7

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

I used the One component For many page in angular.
I want to send a parameter from each component for show any different data.
So I used the this code for call each component in Html:

```
<a  [routerLink]="['categories']" >Page1</a>
<a  [routerLink]="['categories']" >Page2</a>
```

Now in routes i Used this code

```
  {path:'Page1' ,component : ProductCategoriesPagesComponent ,data : {PageNo : 1}},
  {path:'Page2' ,component : ProductCategoriesPagesComponent,data : {PageNo : 2}}
```

Then I used this code in *ProductCategoriesPagesComponent*

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log("data",data);
        });
}
```

But i get

```
data {}
```

In console.
Please Help me how I get parameters from routes 
If I mistake, show the best way for this method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `ActivatedRoute` and get the data from snapshot.

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['PageNo'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data by accessing the route's snapshot like the following:

```
this.route.snapshot.data['PageNo'];
```

So you can do the above instead of subscribing to the observable